# Sending parameters from html to lua

Tags: html, parameters, lua

this is probably an easy question but until now I could not find a way how to do it.
I have an html website which calls a lua file:

```
<meta http-euqiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/cgi-bin/myTest.lua" />
```

This works just fine but I would like to add some arguments to the lua script but can figure out how. I tried something like this but I could not get my hands on the URL in the lua script:

```
<meta http-euqiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/cgi-bin/myTest.lua?test=6&test2=3" />
```

Do you have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add code from your Lua files where you tried to get the params?

Comment: Shure I tried it with: "for k,v in pairs(arg) do print(k,v) end"
 and "print(arg[1])"

Answer (score 1):

In a CGI script, the arguments of a `GET` submission are collected in a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), which is available at the environment variable `QUERY_STRING`.

To read this variable in Lua, use  `os.getenv("QUERY_STRING")`.

You will need to parse the string; `gsub` and `gmatch` can help you there.